# Find similar data from different columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two columns like this. (TC_NO is 11 character, VER_NO is 10 character)

```
TC_NO        VER_NO
19262512794  1926251279    
31124177286  1111111111
31067179194  2222222222
65617278204  6561727820
31483188084  0000000000
```

What i want is, finding VER_NO's first 10 character is the same TC_NO's first 10 characters..

For example for this table the result should be:

```
TC_NO        VER_NO
19262512794  1926251279
65617278204  6561727820
```

How can I do that in Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *
from MYTABLE
where substr(TC_NO,1,10) = VER_NO
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you dont have nulls.

```
select *
from MYTABLE
where substr(TC_NO,1,10)=substr(VER_NO, 1, 10);
```

If you have nulls and you want them to be equal.

```
select *
from MYTABLE
where substr(NVL(TC_NO, '-'),1,10)=substr(NVL(VER_NO, '-'), 1, 10);
```

If you have nulls and you dont want them to be equal.

```
select *
from MYTABLE
where substr(NVL(TC_NO, '-'),1,10)=substr(NVL(VER_NO, '|'), 1, 10);
```

Comment: Good, comprehensive answer.  The first query will work for the "[has] nulls and you don't want them to be equal" scenario as well (`null = null` is false and `substr` will return `null` when used on `null`).

Comment: Good point, I prefer to be explicit when dealing with nulls, in this case  it doesn't matter, but I've found that the same isn't true if that was a outer join with multiple predicates...:D